# "She need not worry" or "she needs to not worry"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, modal-verbs, infinitive-clauses

I just came across this weird use of "need not" on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/HCI_London/status/1241783042483597319):

> Madam/sir,
> My daughter is stuck in Uk . She has lost her [BRP](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits) . She is difficult to return back India home [sic]. Please help

In response, [India in the UK](https://twitter.com/HCI_London) says:

> **She need not worry**. She should stay where she is. Just tell her to keep herself safe. Please delete your tweet.

Shouldn't it be "she **doesn't need to worry**" or "she **needs to not** worry" given that the subject is "she" (singular)? Or is this some kind of grammatical construction I don't know? I believe who wrote it was a native speaker of English and they might be correct. Can someone explain this please?

Comment: "doesn't need to worry" is the more common way to say this in American English, I don't know about Indian English. But it's what the original means.

Comment: "Need not worry" is a known idiom but sounds old-fashioned to me (Midwest USA).

Comment: I think "need not worry" is correct here.  However, "needs to not worry" may be good advice.

Comment: "need not worry" is fine. What *is* strange is that "She is difficult to return back India home"

Comment: @PcMan, I think it's safe to assume that English is not the first language of the original poster of that tweet.

Comment: I would say that the second, "she needs to not worry" is poor English since it splits an infinity!

Comment: @aschepler: It just sounds somewhat British to me; old-fashioned didn't come to mind.  (Canadian English speaker).  As this tweet demonstrates, "need not" is still in current usage by people who learned English with a British flavour.

Comment: @user247327 I think you meant "splits an infinitive", but no, there is nothing wrong with that in modern American English, either spoken or in writing. It's perfectly fine to freely split your infinitives. But don't take my word for it, try this test: ask 5-10 native speakers of American English which sounds or reads better: "I think it's fine to freely split your infinitives", or "I think it's fine to split freely your infinitives". I guarantee that most or all will prefer the first version.

Comment: Actually I would use a different pair of sentences for that survey, so you don't tip your hand about the actual question you're asking! In any case, the point is that [literally no one cares](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally) any more about split infinitives.

Comment: I just noticed a good example that popped up when I searched for [split infinitive](https://www.google.com/search?q=split+infinitive): "She seems to really like it." You could write "She really seems to like it." That would be fine too, but no one would criticize you for either wording. And there is a subtle shade of meaning that is different between the two: "really seems" vs. "really like". Both are OK; choose the one that conveys your meaning most clearly.

Comment: “She need not worry” is almost certainly the exclusive correct choice.

There might - just - be some very obscure circumstances in which  “she needs to not worry” could be stretched to mean “she needs to stop/give up worrying” and please remember, any such circumstances would be obscure at best

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is fine. *Need* in that sentence is used as a modal auxiliary and we use the [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)<sup>1</sup> after modal auxiliaries. It's called a 'semi-modal' because it can act as both a modal verb (like *should, can, might, may*) and a normal/lexical verb (as in *She **doesn't need to worry***).

Try replacing the *need* with another modal auxiliary (for example *should*):

- *She **need not** worry* → *she **should not** worry*

(This is just for comparison and doesn't mean *need not* and *should not* are the same. This use of *need not* mean there's no obligation.)

It behaves the same as other modal auxiliaries and we always use the bare infinitive after them. However, unlike other modal auxiliaries, *need* is restricted to negatives and interrogatives.

---

1. When the base form/infinitive is used without *to*, it's referred to as ‘bare infinitive’ as in *I **saw him dance*** (not **I saw him **to** dance*)

Comment: I really think that this sentence in the first tweet is wrong: "She is difficult to return back India home". What do you think?

Comment: @Man_From_India: Yes, that's incorrect but is not what the op is asking about. Our main concern is the ".. need not... " part. :)

Comment: Yes of course. The non natives still hold their non native identity even in a "native" land :-)

Comment: There's a detailed explanation of the topic on [Collins Dictionary Website](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/dare-and-need).

Comment: Please forgive a critical comment, but I read your first paragraph to a friend, and she replied "What? I have a Master's degree in English and I have never heard of any of that stuff!" You see, "modal auxiliaries" and "bare infinitives" and "semi-modals" are _simply not how modern American English works._ The language is ever-changing and evolving, and the only true test is to have several educated native speakers read or listen, and get their advice on what seems natural to them.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: your friend might find a dip into [CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) useful, to see what people who actually, you know, study English grammar make of it. Modals and bare infinitives are **precisely** how modern English (of whatever variety) works. Of course the language changes, and yes, it's often helpful to ask a native speaker what they make of something; but most native speakers have difficulty explaining **why** something works or doesn't. And that's not much help for a learner who hasn't got a native speaker to hand.

Answer (score 43):

As Void says, *need* (at least for some speakers) is a semimodal, and can be used in both of those ways.

But *She need not worry* has a very different meaning from *She needs to not worry*.

*She need not worry* can be paraphrased as "there is no need for her to worry".

Your second sentence means "There is a need for her to not worry", which is different.

Comment: On the money. Good.

Answer (score 3):

Is this answer redundant?  Let's try anyway, since the implied message of the two is interesting.

"She need not" is an older phrasing for "She does not need to", it's phrased to imply not needing to do something.  It's popular in sales and advice, partly because it gives the client a feeling similar to getting something for nothing, I think.

"She needs to not" is an active instruction to stop, which has two implications.  Using "need" gives a more commanding tone, saying you "need to do this" rather than "should do this".  Combined with "to not" I'd see it as implying the person already doing the action they shouldn't or may to start doing it.  It's not as bad an explicit "Stop [...]" but some people can react negatively if they don't like the implied behaviour.  I find that generally a qualifier gets attached ("When she gets there, she needs to not ...") and/or rephrased to a "better" action ("remain calm" rather than "not worry").

To contrast with a slightly different action:

- "She need not panic" will hopefully be interpreted as "there's nothing you'll need to panic about".
- "She needs to not panic" might be interpreted as "You're panicking and need to stop".

Perhaps you've heard an advert use the words "You need not delay"?  Sneaky, right?  If they say

> You should buy this now!

they'd sound unpleasant and you might not be as accepting of their claims.  But if they instead phrase it to something commanding, like

> You need not delay, our operators are standing by to take your order.

then they're implying that you have no reason to not buy it immediately, without actually telling you that you should.

Another one might be changing "You don't need to worry about" to "You need not worry", as a way to convince you that there isn't something you definitely should worry about.  This kind of phrasing isn't always reason to be suspicious, but it is certainly understandable why a lot of stereotype dodgy salesmen characters use it while trying to sell their miracle product, before disappearing in the next scene.

Answer (score 2):

"She need not worry", or "she needn't worry", is indeed right.

*Needn't* functions as a modal verb in that sentence (and when it's a modal verb, it doesn't take on -s in third person singular). I'm not sure about the usage though, it seems to only be common in some English-speaking countries, not all (I think a Brit is more likely to say this than an American).

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'need not worry' means, she does not need the feeling 'worry', but 'need to not worry' means, she need to stop feel 'worry'.

Basically

- Need not worry → Not necessary feeling
- Need not to worry → Not necessary to feel (feeling as action)
- Need to not worry → Necessary to stop feeling (feeling as action)

The main point is the difference of usage between verbs and nouns with 'need'.

Comment: hmm, is "Need not to worry" correct? Could you provide an example use?

Comment: @ikegami: "she need not to worry" definitely sounds wrong to my ear.  (Canadian English speaker).  I can't think of any surrounding context that would make "need not to worry" work in a sentence, and I'm pretty sure it's not grammatical in *this* context.

Comment: @PeterCordes As a native speaker of American English, I agree. I can't think of any case where that would work. Interestingly, there is a similar phrase that may not be grammatically "correct" but is in common usage today, which makes it correct: "Not to worry, I will take care of that for you." This may be more commonly phrased "Don't worry, I will take care of that for you." But either one would be fine in casual usage.

Comment: Oh, that discussion brought some complications. Firstly, I have to tell that I'm not a native speaker. Also I've learned English with speaking / chatting with non-native speakers. Grammatically I agree with you there's no usage but I run into daily chats sometimes and I think its meaning is this.